# Shrinking the array with lodash merge behavior

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am facing an issue with the lodash merge. Seeking your advice.

I have an original array of form:

// Input-1: My original array

```
"app_resource_storage_details": [
            {
                "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",
                "volume_name": "db1_data",
                "volume_uuid": "293ad9f3-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36992",
                "app_volume_type": "Data"
            },
            {
                "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",
                "volume_name": "db1_ts1",
                "volume_uuid": "36d62f80-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36992",
                "app_volume_type": "Log"
            },
            {
                "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",  
                "volume_name": "db1_log",
                "volume_uuid": "36d62f80-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36982",
                "app_volume_type": "Log"
            }
        ],
```

When I am adding more elements into this array the merge is behaving correctly. My merge code is:

```
        const _ = require('lodash');

        const userDocContent = _.merge(origDoc, document);  // HERE I am using lodashmerge
        const updateObj = {
            ...userDocContent,
            tenancyResourceId : origDoc.tenancyResourceId,
        };
        const options = { upsert: false , returnOriginal: false};  
        const result =  await getCollection(fastify, database, collection).findOneAndReplace(filter, updateObj, options);
        const updatedDoc = {_id: result.value._id, ...updateObj};
        return updatedDoc;
```

Now when I am expanding the array, its working nicely. But when I am shrinking it with the following payload:

// Input-2: This is the input I am passing.

```
    "app_resource_storage_details": [
                {
                    "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                    "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",
                    "volume_name": "db1_data",
                    "volume_uuid": "293ad9f3-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36982",
                    "app_volume_type": "Data"
                },
                {
                    "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                    "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",
                    "volume_name": "db1_log",
                    "volume_uuid": "36d62f80-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36982",
                    "app_volume_type": "Log"
                }
    ]
```

I am getting a result like:

```
                "app_resource_storage_details": [
            {
                "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",
                "volume_name": "db1_data",
                "volume_uuid": "293ad9f3-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36992",
                "app_volume_type": "Data"
            },
            {
                "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",
                "volume_name": "db1_log",
                "volume_uuid": "36d62f80-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36992",
                "app_volume_type": "Log"
            },
            {
                "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",  // This element should not be there.
                "volume_name": "db1_ts1",
                "volume_uuid": "36d62f80-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36982",
                "app_volume_type": "Log"
            }
        ]
```

My expected output:

```
 "app_resource_storage_details": [
                {
                    "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                    "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",
                    "volume_name": "db1_data",
                    "volume_uuid": "293ad9f3-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36982",
                    "app_volume_type": "Data"
                },
                {
                    "storage_system_name": "vs2",
                    "storage_system_uuid": "844fb236-daeb-11eb-a1c5-005056b36982",
                    "volume_name": "db1_log",
                    "volume_uuid": "36d62f80-21df-11ec-ae67-005056b36982",
                    "app_volume_type": "Log"
                }
    ]
```

I think I am not able to merge it properly with the intention of sometimes the array elements will expand, sometimes it will shrink.

May be there is a better way in lodash to do it which I am not aware of.

Any advice / proper use of lodash is highly appreciated.

Comment: If we could see input and expected output perhaps we could find a way that is not even using lodash

Comment: Apology if I was not clear in the question. My original array was mentioned as "Input-1: My original array". 
I am passing the array (in the intention of shrinking it): "Input-2: This is the input I am passing." (Note that the "volume_name": "db1_ts1" is not passed here. So 3 elements array is expected to shrink to 2 elements).
The expected result: "My expected output:".

Hope it's bit clear now.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are just removing the object containing `"db1_ts1"`

Comment: Yes. So I have 3 elements in the array. I want to shrink it by 1 element. But as a result I am getting the merged result as 3 elements only. I wanted the merged result to contain 2 elements (db1_data and db1_log).
Note that: some cases I may want to expand, some cases I may want to shrimk. The array can be nested also. So I used lodahs merge. Which seems is not helping me in shriking.

Comment: Basically I am implementing the REST API PATCH behavior. Where user can send an array (which can be nested also or deep inside an object) of more elements (expand), less elements (shrink). So I am looking for an elegant way how can I merge the payload to the original content to get the new content.
So I used lodash merge. 
What other options /  elegant solution(s) I can use. Or any other loadash function.